# Prove that every element in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}}$ is a sum of $p$-potent and nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory

I need to prove that in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}}$, every element $x$ can be written as $x = a + b$, where $a^{p} = a$ ($a$ is called $p$-potent), $p$ is a prime number and $b^{m} = 0$, for some $m>0$.

I know that $0,1$ are $p$-potent and $-1$ is also a $p$-potent if $p$ odd. And in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}}$,
$p$ and the multiples of $p$ are nilpotent. Instead of checking every element, i want to prove it in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an element $x \in \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ in base $p$ as $x = c_0 + c_1 p + \cdots + c_{n-1} p^{n-1}$ with $c_i \in \{0, 1, \ldots, p-1\}$. Using Hensel's lemma we can find a root $a$ of the polynomial $T^p - T$ mod $p^n$ such that $a \equiv c_0 \pmod{p}$. Then $b := x - a$ is divisible by $p$, so $b^n$ is divisible by $p^n$, hence $b^n = 0$.

Comment: As an aside, writing $x = a + b$ with the given properties reminds me of [Jordan decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition#Decomposition_of_a_linear_operator) of a linear operator. I wonder if there's a way to do this problem by considering $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ as an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and left multiplication by $x$ as a linear operator...